# For Dirichlet's test, is it true that if $\ a_1=1\ $ then $\ \left\vert \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n b_n \right\vert \leq M\ ?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I think I might be gaining more understanding of [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) visually.

For Dirichlet's test, is it true that if $\ a_1=1\ $ then $\ \displaystyle\left\vert \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  a_n b_n \right\vert \leq M\ ?$

I think this because $\ \displaystyle\left\vert \sum_{n=1}^{k}\ b_n \right\vert\ \leq M\implies\ \sum_{n=1}^{k}\ b_n\in\ B(0+0i,M)=\{\ \vert z\vert\leq M:z\in\mathbb{C}\ \}\ $ for every $\ k.\ $

Therefore it seems to me that if $\ a_1=1\ $ and $\ \{a_n\}\ $ is decreasing with $\ a_n\to 0,\ $ then the terms of $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k}  a_n b_n\ $ ought to also be "bouncing around" inside $\ B(0+0i,M).\ $ Is this picture correct? And if so is there a proof of this? Or is the proof of this covered in the proof of Dirichlet's test?

Comment: I don't understand the significance of $a_1=1$.

Comment: @AlvinL Presumably the intention is that the bound is with the same $M$ given for the partial sums of $\sum b_n$.

Comment: @AlvinL If $a_1>1$, then you can take $a_1=3, a_2=a_3=\dots=0$ and $b_1=1, b_2=b_3=\cdots = 0$, and you have $\left|\sum_{n=1}^N b_n\right| < 2=M$ for all $N$, but you also have $\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n b_n\right| = 3 \geq 2 = M$...

Comment: Intuitively, yes, I think this is true. Because the $a_i$ "pull" the $b_i$ closer to the origin. So if the partial sums of $b_i$ are bounded by $M$, surely the partial sums of $a_ib_i$ would be too.

Comment: Something is not getting right with the $0+0i$... have you tried Abel`s test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test ?

Comment: @Mabadai I am even less familiar with Abel's test than Dirichlet's test. I don't see how Abel's test helps answer my question... And I don't get your comment about the $0+0i.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\ a_1=1,\ \{a_n\}\ $ is monotonically decreasing with $\ a_n\to 0,\ $ and suppose that $\ \displaystyle\left\vert\sum_{n=1}^k b_n\right\vert \leq M\quad \forall k\in\mathbb{N}.\ $ We can use the result of Dirichlet's Test also, that is, $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n b_n\ $ converges. I first aim to show that $\ \displaystyle\left\vert\sum_{n=1}^k a_n b_n\right\vert \leq M\quad \forall k\in\mathbb{N}.$

We can make use of the following identity, which holds for all $\ k\geq 2$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^k a_n b_n = \sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \left( (a_n-a_{n+1}) \sum_{j=1}^n b_j \right) + a_k\sum_{n=1}^k b_n.$$

For $\ k=1,\ $ we have $\ \left\vert\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^k a_n b_n\right\vert = \vert a_1 b_1 \vert = a_1 \vert b_1 \vert \leq \vert b_1\vert \leq M.$

For every $\ k\geq2, $ we have:

\begin{align} \left\vert\sum_{n=1}^{k} a_n b_n\right\vert = \left\vert\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \left( (a_n-a_{n+1}) \sum_{j=1}^n b_j \right) + a_k\sum_{n=1}^k b_n\right\vert\\
\\
\leq \sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \left( (a_n-a_{n+1}) \left\vert\sum_{j=1}^n b_j\right\vert \right) + a_k\left\vert\sum_{n=1}^k b_n \right\vert \\
\\
\leq \left( \sum_{n=1}^{k-1} (a_n-a_{n+1}) M\right) + a_n M = a_1 M \leq M.\\
\\
\end{align}
$$$$

This means that, for each $\ k\geq 1,\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k} a_n b_n $ is a point inside the closed disc $\ \{\ \vert z\vert\leq M:z\in\mathbb{C}\ \}.\ $ Since $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n b_n\ $ converges, $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n b_n\ $ must converge to a member of $\ \{\ \vert z\vert\leq M:z\in\mathbb{C}\ \},\ $ which implies that $\ \displaystyle\left\vert \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  a_n b_n \right\vert \leq M.$

Answer (score 6):

Let $T_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k$ be the partial sum of $(b_n)$. Then by summation by parts,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k b_k
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k (T_k - T_{k-1}) \\
&= a_n T_n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (a_k - a_{k+1}) T_k.
\end{align*}

If $T_k$ is bounded and $(a_k)$ decreases to $0$, then as $n \to \infty$ the above sum converges to

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k b_k = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (a_k - a_{k+1}) T_k. $$

In particular, if $(T_n)$ is bounded by $M$, then

$$ \left| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k b_k \right| \leq M \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (a_k - a_{k+1}) = M a_1. $$

This resolves OP's question.